# Understanding a docker entrypoint script

Tags: bash, sed, docker

The script is located here: https://github.com/docker-library/ghost/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [[ "$*" == npm*start* ]]; then
    baseDir="$GHOST_SOURCE/content"
    for dir in "$baseDir"/*/ "$baseDir"/themes/*/; do
        targetDir="$GHOST_CONTENT/${dir#$baseDir/}"
        mkdir -p "$targetDir"
        if [ -z "$(ls -A "$targetDir")" ]; then
            tar -c --one-file-system -C "$dir" . | tar xC "$targetDir"
        fi
    done

    if [ ! -e "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js" ]; then
        sed -r '
            s/127\.0\.0\.1/0.0.0.0/g;
            s!path.join\(__dirname, (.)/content!path.join(process.env.GHOST_CONTENT, \1!g;
        ' "$GHOST_SOURCE/config.example.js" > "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js"
    fi

    ln -sf "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js" "$GHOST_SOURCE/config.js"

    chown -R user "$GHOST_CONTENT"

    set -- gosu user "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

From what I know, it says that if you use some variation of `npm start` to move some files around from `$GHOST_SOURCE` to `$GHOST_CONTENT`, do something to the `config.js` file, link the config file, set ownership of the content files, and then execute `npm start` as the user `user`. Otherwise, it just runs your commands normally.

The specifics are what are hard for me to understand because there are a lot of things from bash that I've never seen before. So I have a lot of questions.

```
for dir in "$baseDir"/*/ "$baseDir"/themes/*/; do
```

In the above, why do they specify both `/*/` and `/themes/*/`? Shouldn't `/*/` contain themes? Is `*` not a wildcard for some reason?

```
targetDir="$GHOST_CONTENT/${dir#$baseDir/}"
```

In the above, what is the point of `#` in the variable expansion?

```
tar -c --one-file-system -C "$dir" . | tar xC "$targetDir"
```

In the above, does this somehow save time? Why not use something like rsync? I understand the point of `-C`, but why `-c` and `--one-file-system`?

```
sed -r '
        s/127\.0\.0\.1/0.0.0.0/g;
        s!path.join\(__dirname, (.)/content!path.join(process.env.GHOST_CONTENT, \1!g;
    ' "$GHOST_SOURCE/config.example.js" > "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js"
```

What does this `sed` command do? I know it's a replacement, but why the `"$GHOST_SOURCE/config.example.js" > "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js"` as the end?

```
ln -sf "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js" "$GHOST_SOURCE/config.js"
```

In the above, what is the point of this symlink? Why try to link them to each other if both files already exist?

```
set -- gosu user "$@"
```

In the above what does calling `set` with no args do?

I hope that's not too much. I felt making a separate question for each of these would be too much especially since it's all related to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for dir in "$baseDir"/*/ "$baseDir"/themes/*/; do
> ```
>
> In the above, why do they specify both `/*/` and `/themes/*/`? Shouldn't
>   `/*/` contain themes? Is `*` not a wildcard for some reason?

themes/ is in the first match, but themes/*/ is not, so you need the second entry to include the contents of themes.

> ```
> targetDir="$GHOST_CONTENT/${dir#$baseDir/}"
> ```
>
> In the above, what is the point of # in the variable expansion?

It removes the $baseDir prefix from $dir. So for example:

```
bash$ dir=/home/bmitch/data/docker
bash$ echo $dir
/home/bmitch/data/docker
bash$ echo ${dir#/home/bmitch}
/data/docker
```

> ```
> tar -c --one-file-system -C "$dir" . | tar xC "$targetDir"
> ```
>
> In the above, does this somehow save time? Why not use something like
>   rsync? I understand the point of -C, but why -c and --one-file-system?

rsync may not be installed on every machine by default, tar is fairly universal. The -c is to create, vs extract, and --one-file-system avoids tar continuing to an outside mount point (nfs, symlink to root, etc).

> ```
> sed -r '
>     s/127\.0\.0\.1/0.0.0.0/g;
>     s!path.join\(__dirname, (.)/content!path.join(process.env.GHOST_CONTENT, \1!g;
> ' "$GHOST_SOURCE/config.example.js" > "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js"
> ```
>
> What does this sed command do? I know it's a replacement, but why the
>   "$GHOST_SOURCE/config.example.js" > "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js" as the
>   end?

config.example.js is the input (last arg to the sed), config.js is the output (after the >). So it takes the config.example.js, change the ip address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, effectively listening on all interfaces/ip's instead of just internally on the loopback. The second half of the sed is changing the path.join arguments from __dirname to process.env.GHOST_CONTENT.

> ```
> ln -sf "$GHOST_CONTENT/config.js" "$GHOST_SOURCE/config.js"
> ```
>
> In the above, what is the point of this symlink? Why try to link them
>   to each other if both files already exist?

The $GHOST_SOURCE/config.js is replaced (-f) with a link to $GHOST_CONTENT/config.js. Symbolic links give a file name reference to another actual file, so there will be two names, but one copy of the data, which means you will only have a single configuration in this situation.

> ```
> set -- gosu user "$@"
> ```
>
> In the above what does calling set with no args do?

This changes the values of $1, $2, ... $n to be $1=gosu, $2=user, $3=the old $1, $4=the old $2..., essentially adding the gosu and user to the beginning of the passed parameters to the script. The -- makes sure that set doesn't interpret any values from $@ as a flag for itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! If you don't mind could you answer the one last question I recently added about `set --`?

Comment: The bash man page has a lot of details, quite a long read. Under the "Parameter Expansion" section are details about `${...#...}`.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, which probably could be a completely new question. Any idea why this script uses `set --` instead of `exec`? Normally I see `exec gosu`

Comment: It does use `exec` on the last line. The `set -- gosu user $@` just changes the final `exec` command to effectively be an `exec gosu user $@`, but only when the initial `if` statement is true.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. You've helped me get through hours of banging my head on this simple script.

Comment: Great explanations; as for the script itself: it's notable that it uses `sed -r`, which won't work on OS X (which uses an older BSD `sed`; `-E` would work with both GNU and OS X `sed`, within the constraints of the platform-specific ERE dialects - fine with the regex at hand); as a minor point of interest: the original script mixes Bash's `[[ ... ]]` with POSIX-compliant `[ ... ]`.